# Can't get user_id Laravel with Auth::user() just with \Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

sorry if it is a noob question, but I'm trying to learn laravel on laracast and can't solve this by my own.

there is a store function on my ArticlesController like this:

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $article = new Article($request->all());

        Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);

        return redirect('articles');
    }
```

and it returns a blank page, making clear that is some error, but if I change to

```
    \Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);
```

it works as expected, saving the article with the `user_id` field.

I tried import with `use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController;` but I think this is not the way.

*obs: Laravel 5.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In modern PHP, if you see the following at the top of a file

```
namespace App\Foo\Bar;
```

it means all the code inside that file in part of the `App\Foo\Bar` namespace.  If you try to use a namespaceless class inside this file

```
$object = new Auth;
```

PHP will assume you want to use the class.  In other words, it's the same as saying

```
$object = \App\Foo\Bar\Auth;
```

When you say

```
\Auth
```

you're telling PHP "use the **global**, top level namespace class named `Auth`.

This is a perfectly valid use of PHP, by the way.  However, if you don't like using the global `\` -- you can import the `\Auth` class into your PHP file (sometimes referred to as a "module" in other languages") by using the `use` statement.

```
namespace App\Foo\Bar;

//pull in the global class `Auth`
use Auth;
//...

$foo = new Auth;
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, think it is part of the basics that I don't get yet... maybe with time and more online lessons. =)